# Why does GDB hang when using OpenOCD in remote pipe mode?

Tags: gdb, openocd

I'm using GDB and OpenOCD to debug a simple program on my STM32F4DISCOVERY board on Windows. This works fine when starting OpenOCD separately, and using TCP/IP to connect to it, with something like this:

```
target remote localhost:3333
```

When I'm done, I can shut down GDB using `quit` as normal. I would like, however, to use GDB in "remote pipe" mode, instead of needing to start and stop OpenOCD manually. This seems like a somewhat ideal configuration to me. When I do this, however, I cannot exit GDB, as it hangs when I attempt to exit.

The OpenOCD log file shows that the GDB connection was dropped:

```
Info : dropped 'gdb' connection
```

But GDB never exits:

```
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [Remote target] will be detached.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
Detaching from program: yagarto_sample.elf, Remote target
Ending remote debugging.
```

The `disconnect` command similarly hangs, never returing. Not even Ctrl-C will wake up GDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug in OpenOCD related to a change made by GDB. A bit of detail is [here](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=34112), and a [patch](http://openocd.zylin.com/#/c/993/) has been submitted, and a workaround is provided:

Add this to your cfg:

```
$_TARGETNAME configure -event gdb-detach { shutdown }
```

I tested this workaround, and it does work, but in the end, pipe mode is so slow on Windows that I chose to use TCP, even though it is less convenient.